# Reading Random Access File with Buffered Reader

Tags: java, file, io, java-io

i am trying to read a huge file ( > 1GB) , i am thinking that reading it as a random access file with a buffered reader would be efficient.

i need to read the file line by line and parse it

However being new to JAVA IO Api , i'm not sure how can i do this..

i appreciate your help.

Comment: You can only read a random byte, not a random character (as they can vary in length) What are you trying to do was these classes doesn't work well together?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Do you need to read the entire file?  Read something at a fixed offset in the middle of the file?  Read something that you have to search for in the middle of the file?  Are you just trying to make a read of the entire file "go faster"?  Q: What exactly is the "problem" you're trying to resolve?

Comment: i need to read the file line by line and parse it, i need it to be as fast as possible

Comment: `BufferedReader` and `RandomAccessFile` are completely orthogonal concepts.  Buffered reader does character decoding (as do all `Reader`s) and buffers the input so that it can find line endings and thus give you whole lines at a time.  Random access files are for reading from an arbitrary byte index in a file.  What are you really trying to do?

Comment: @user: if you want to read the file line by line, forget using random access; random access is only useful if you want to jump to a specific place in the file and avoid reading everything before it.  You don't want that: you want to read every line in order.  Just use a `BufferedReader`, of which there are many examples (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2500107/how-should-i-read-from-a-buffered-reader)

Comment: If you "need to read the file line by line", then you want a buffered reader :)

Comment: PS:   If you're doing a lot of processing on the string you read, you probably also want to use StringBuilder (you *don't* want to do a lot of processing on "String"). IMHO...

Comment: If you are dealing with a variable length file where data keeps coming (ex log file) i wrote one for me and its here http://stackoverflow.com/a/19867481/1282907

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Java's BufferedReader for this:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
  // Do some stuff with the line
}
```

`fileName` is the path to the file you want to read.

Comment: Note that `FileReader` assumes that the given file is encoded with the default character encoding. There's no way to tell it otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to read all of it and from the beginning? You can use a RandomAccessFile to jump to different parts of the file if you know what byte you can start at. I think it is the seek function that does this.

Comment: i dont care where i start , as long as i end up reading the whole file line by line

Comment: then I thin jayeff answer is your best bet

Answer (score -1):

While it is perfectly doable in java, I wanted to suggest based on my experience:

If you're on Unix platform, you may use external shell script for searching through the GBs of log. `sed` is very optimum for this purpose. Specific usage here: http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html

Call shell script through java file whenever you need to read/grep through the log file.

**How?**

1) In your java code, use `ProcessBuilder` class. It can take shell script as arg to constructor

`ProcessBuilder obj = new ProcessBuilder("FastLogRead.sh");`

2) Create object for Process

`Process process = obj.start();`

3) You can read the output of this shell, directly in your BufferedRead through this

`BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));`

**Pros:**

Speeds up execution by avg. 10 times (I searched through around 4GB log file)

**Cons:**

Some developers don't like bringing in light-weight shell script in realms of java, hence want to go for java's `RandomAccessFile`. This is justified.

For your case, you may choose between standardization and performance.